# Check for waitable timer elapsed

Tags: c, timer

So, i'm trying to make a waitable timer in C and perform a task if the timer has elapsed. I used the waitable timer example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687008%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that used `WaitForSingleObject` to make it wait for the timer to finish but I'd like to continue my program and check if the timer has elapsed at a later stage.

Can i just use `WaitForSingleObject` with a time of 1ms to check if the timer is done or is there a better way? I couldn't find anything in the MSDN list and I don't need less than a seconds resolution for the timer in any case, so waiting 1ms shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to poll a waitable timer?  According to MSDN,

> If dwMilliseconds is zero, the function does not enter a wait state if the object is not signaled; it always returns immediately

So if you call `WaitForSingleObject(h, 0)`, it will check if your timer is signalled and return immediately.

Comment: Oh, silly me. I completely misinterpreted that part. Anyway thank you very much for the help with clarifying that.